# Why does my php script abort when downloading large files?

Tags: php

I have a script that let's users download .zip files. The script works great with files of around 70MB but whenever I try and download files of around 700MB the download never completes ( I get an error or the file is just incomplete, around 500MB).
I know this question get asked a lot here but I just can't find any answers that solve the problem. Is there anything I should try? 
Thanks.

Php download code

```
$strDownload = $strDownloadFolder.$arrCheck['file'];
                if(file_exists($strDownload)){


                        // also, replaces the file location with a preset one ('./myfiles/' in this example)
    $file_path  = $arrCheck['file'];
    $path_parts = pathinfo($file_path);
    $file_name  = $path_parts['basename'];
    $file_ext   = $path_parts['extension'];
    $file_path  = 'files/' . $file_name;

     // allow a file to be streamed instead of sent as an attachment
    $is_attachment = isset($_REQUEST['stream']) ? false : true;

    // make sure the file exists
    if (is_file($file_path))
    {
        $file_size  = filesize($file_path);
        $file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
        if ($file)
        {
            // set the headers, prevent caching
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: -1");
            header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");

            // set appropriate headers for attachment or streamed file
            if ($is_attachment)
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
            else
                    header('Content-Disposition: inline;');

            // set the mime type based on extension, add yours if needed.
            $ctype_default = "application/octet-stream";
            $content_types = array(
                    "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
                    "zip" => "application/zip",
                    "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
                    "mpg" => "video/mpeg",
                    "avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
            );
            $ctype = isset($content_types[$file_ext]) ? $content_types[$file_ext] : $ctype_default;
            header("Content-Type: " . $ctype);

            //check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
            if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
            {
                list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
                if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
                {
                    //multiple ranges could be specified at the same time, but for simplicity only serve the first range
                    //http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00.txt
                    list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    $range = '';
                    header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                    exit;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $range = '';
            }

            //figure out download piece from range (if set)
            list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);

            //set start and end based on range (if set), else set defaults
            //also check for invalid ranges.
            $seek_end   = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($file_size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($file_size - 1));
            $seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs(intval($seek_start)),0);

            //Only send partial content header if downloading a piece of the file (IE workaround)
            if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($file_size - 1))
            {
                header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
                header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$file_size);
                header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));
            }
            else
              header("Content-Length: $file_size");

            header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

            set_time_limit(0);
            fseek($file, $seek_start);

            while(!feof($file)) 
            {
                print(@fread($file, 1024*8));
                ob_flush();
                flush();
                if (connection_status()!=0) 
                {
                    @fclose($file);
                    exit;
                }           
            }

            // file save was a success
            @fclose($file);
            exit;
        }
        else 
        {
            // file couldn't be opened
            header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
            exit;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // file does not exist
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        exit;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Likely because your server configuration has a max file size \ max post size or memory buffer issue.

Comment: What exactly have you tried that hasn't solved the problem?

Comment: Script timing out?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following in your php.ini:

Edit:  Realized that it's trying to send a file not recieve it check:

```
max_execution_time = 0
```

Your server is likely timing out.  The above will set it to no-timeout (not recommended for a production environment, but you can test to see if this is the issue and then adjust accordingly).  You can also adjust this for just this page using:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

In the php script itself, if it's allowed.  Also note if you use max_execution_time you'll have to restart your web service for it to take effect.

Comment: OP is talking about download, not upload

Comment: max_execution_time in the php.ini file is set to 30. What should I increase it too?

Comment: Try setting it to 0 and see if it works, and then fiddle with it untill it's accomodating your large file size.  The number is how long in seconds you wish to allow a script to run

Comment: 0 means infinite